# GraphQL - Chillicream Pagination on Property

Tags: graphql

I don't know if this is the right place, but I am having a problem with Chillicream:
I have a class: Fruit in which there is a property that is a List Molecules
This Molecule is a class with it's own properties.
on this one I used to have the annotation:

```
[UseOffsetPaging(IncludeTotalCount = true)]
public List<Molecule> Molecules{ get; set; }
```

And it would work fine, now I need to remove the annotation from here, since I don't want the dependency to the package on this project, and want to define it on the GraphqlSetup:

```
services.AddGraphQLServer()
    .SetPagingOptions(new PagingOptions
    {
        MaxPageSize = 100,
        AllowBackwardPagination = true,
        DefaultPageSize = 10,
        IncludeTotalCount = true
    })
    .AddTypeExtension<FruitExtensions>()
```

In the FruitExtensions:

```
public class FruitExtensions : ObjectTypeExtension<Fruit>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Fruit> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Field(x => x.Molecules).UseOffsetPaging(options: new HotChocolate.Types.Pagination.PagingOptions
        {
            MaxPageSize = 100,
            AllowBackwardPagination = true,
            DefaultPageSize = 10,
            IncludeTotalCount = true
        });
    }
}
```

The problem here is that this solution doesn't work, it shows the error:
"The field `pageInfo` does not exist on the type `Molecule`."
"The field `items` does not exist on the type `Molecule`"
If this shouldn't be posted here please let me know. Thanks for any help : D

Comment: This should not be a type extension `public class FruitType : ObjectType<Fruit>`. Second you must register this type `.AddType<FruitType>.` If you use our source generator we will generate a model and auto-register GraphQL types.